# Network Communication Diagram Help

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

I tried using msc package but it suffers from many issues. This is why I decided to draw it like the following.

My code:

```
    %!TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}%to use righ=of

\begin{document}
    \def\nodeTextWidth{4.5cm}
    \def\levelOne{2cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=7mm and 5mm,
    every node/.append style={very thick},
    entity/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=\nodeTextWidth},
    hiddenentity/.style={,rectangle, minimum width=\nodeTextWidth},
    operation/.style={draw=black,thick,fill=white,rounded corners=0mm,text width=\nodeTextWidth,font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt, text centered},
    myarrow/.style={line width=2pt,black,-latex},
    textAboveArrow/.style={inner sep=2pt,outer sep=4pt, fill=white,font=\footnotesize}
    ]

    \node[entity] (bank) {Eve};
    \node[entity, right=of bank] (smartMeter)  {Alice};
    \node[entity, right=of smartMeter] (utilityProvider)  {Bob};

    \node[operation, below=of bank] (accountDescription) { $xxxxxxx$};

    %VERTICAL LINES
    \draw [very thick] (bank)  --  (accountDescription)--(0,-11);
    \node[mark size=3pt,color=black] at (0,-11) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
    \draw [very thick] (smartMeter)--++(0,-11);
    \node[mark size=3pt,color=black] at (\nodeTextWidth+5.5mm,-11) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
    \draw [very thick] (utilityProvider)--++(0,-11);
    \node[mark size=3pt,color=black] at (\nodeTextWidth*2+11mm,-11) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};

    %=============================== AUTHENTICATION PHASE =======================
    %LEVEL ONE COMMUNICATION 
    \node[hiddenentity,below=of accountDescription](bankL2){};
    \node[hiddenentity,right=of bankL2](SML2){};
    %
    \draw [myarrow] (bankL2.center)--(SML2.center) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {$xxxxxxx$};

    \node[hiddenentity,below=of SML2](SML3){};
    \node[hiddenentity,right=of SML3](UPL3){};
    \draw [myarrow] (SML3.center)--(UPL3.center) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {$xxxxxxx$};

    \node[hiddenentity,below=of SML3](SML4){};
    \node[hiddenentity,right=of SML4](UPL4){};
    \draw [myarrow] (UPL4.center)--(SML4.center) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {$xxxxxxx$};

    \node[operation, below=of SML4] (findSigma) {Find the value of $xxxxxxx$};
    \node[hiddenentity,right=of findSigma](UPL5){};

    \draw[thick] ($(accountDescription.north west)+(-0.1,0.15)$) rectangle ($(UPL5.south east)+(0.1,-0.25)$) node[below=2.5mm of smartMeter,fill=white, draw, rectangle]{\textit{First Phase}} ;

    %======================== REPORTING PHASE ===============================
    \node[hiddenentity,below=of findSigma](SML6){};
    \node[hiddenentity,left=of findSigma](BL6){};
    \node[hiddenentity,below=of BL6](BL7){};
    \node[hiddenentity,right=of SML6](UPL6){};
    \draw [myarrow] (SML6.center)--(UPL6.center) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {xxxxxxx};

    \node[operation, below=of UPL6] (recordPayment) {xxxxxxx};
    \draw[thick] ($(BL7.north west)+(-0.1,0.25)$) rectangle ($(recordPayment.south east)+(0.1,-0.1)$) node[below=2.5mm of BL6,fill=white, draw, rectangle, rounded corners=0mm]{\textit{Second Phase}} ;
    %==================== REWARDING PHASE ========================
    \node[hiddenentity,below=of recordPayment](UPL8){};
    \node[hiddenentity,left=of UPL8](SML8){};
    \node[hiddenentity,left=of SML8](BL8){};
    \draw [myarrow] (SML8.center)--(UPL8.center) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {xxxxxxx};

    \node[hiddenentity,below=of UPL8](UPL9){};
    \node[hiddenentity,left=of UPL9](SML9){};
    \node[hiddenentity,left=of SML9](BL9){};
    \draw [myarrow] (UPL9.center)--(BL9.center) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {xxxxxxx};

    \draw[thick] ($(BL8.north west)+(-0.15,0.5)$) rectangle ($(UPL9.south east)+(0.15,-0.1)$) node[below=16mm of BL7,fill=white, draw, rectangle]{\textit{Third Phase}} ;       
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

***I have two primary issues:***

**First Issue:**
When this is compiled with pdflatex it shows correct output as follow (Third Phase positioning is incorrect): 
[image]

However, when I compile it with xelatex (required for my paper) the circles at the end of vertical line disappear. as follows. 
[image]

**Second issue:**

Is there a better way to draw rectangles around a group of nodes and create a label as in (First Phase, Second Phase, and Third Phase) to be centered using relative positioning. Third Phase should be similar to Second Phase positioning.

Comment: As for your second issue: yes, there is the `fit` library, which allows you to draw a frame around a given set of nodes. Unfortunately, I hardly ever use `xelatex`, so I can't answer your question. (Sometimes it is better to ask two separate questions for that reason.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code has been compiled with xelatex. I don't know what was the problem with plotmarks, but I've replaced them with `-{Circle[]}` arrows (`arrows.meta` library) and they are shown again.

I've also made some other changes on your code. Mainly I've only used `hiddenentity` nodes when needed. I've replaced them with `coordinate` nodes.

Phase rectangles have been replaced by `fit` nodes. In order to keep simetry some `hiddenentity` nodes have been used.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, arrows.meta, fit}%to use righ=of

\begin{document}
    \def\nodeTextWidth{4.5cm}
    \def\levelOne{2cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=7mm and 5mm,
    every node/.append style={very thick},
    entity/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=\nodeTextWidth},
    hiddenentity/.style={,rectangle, minimum width=\nodeTextWidth},
    operation/.style={draw=black,thick,fill=white,rounded corners=0mm,text width=\nodeTextWidth,font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt, text centered},
    myarrow/.style={line width=2pt,black,-latex},
    textAboveArrow/.style={inner sep=2pt,outer sep=4pt, fill=white,font=\footnotesize}
    ]

    \node[entity] (bank) {Eve};
    \node[entity, right=of bank] (smartMeter)  {Alice};
    \node[entity, right=of smartMeter] (utilityProvider)  {Bob};

    \node[operation, below=of bank] (accountDescription) { $xxxxxxx$};

    %VERTICAL LINES
    \draw [very thick, -{Circle[]}] (bank)  --  (accountDescription)--(0,-11);
%    \node[mark size=3pt,color=black] at (0,-11) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
    \draw [very thick, -{Circle[]}] (smartMeter)--++(0,-11);
%    \node[mark size=3pt,color=black] at (\nodeTextWidth+5.5mm,-11) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
    \draw [very thick, -{Circle[]}] (utilityProvider)--++(0,-11);
%    \node[mark size=3pt,color=black] at (\nodeTextWidth*2+11mm,-11) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};

    %=============================== AUTHENTICATION PHASE =======================
    %LEVEL ONE COMMUNICATION 
%    \node[hiddenentity,below=of accountDescription](bankL2){};
    \coordinate[below=of accountDescription] (bankL2);
    \draw[myarrow] (bankL2)--(bankL2-|smartMeter) coordinate (SML2) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {$xxxxxxx$};
%    \node[hiddenentity,right=of bankL2](SML2){};
%    %
%    \draw [myarrow] (bankL2.center)--(SML2.center) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {$xxxxxxx$};

    \coordinate[below=of SML2](SML3);
%    \node[hiddenentity,right=of SML3](UPL3){};
    \draw [myarrow] (SML3)--(SML3-|utilityProvider) coordinate(UPL3) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {$xxxxxxx$};

    \coordinate[below=of UPL3](UPL4){};
%    \node[hiddenentity,right=of SML4](UPL4){};
    \draw [myarrow] (UPL4)--(UPL4-|SML3) coordinate (SML4) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {$xxxxxxx$};

    \node[operation, below=of SML4] (findSigma) {Find the value of $xxxxxxx$};
    \node[hiddenentity,right=of findSigma](UPL5){};

    \node[fit=(accountDescription) (UPL5), draw, thick, label={[font=\itshape, fill=white, draw, anchor=center]90:First Phase}] {};

%    \draw[thick] ($(accountDescription.north west)+(-0.1,0.15)$) rectangle ($(UPL5.south east)+(0.1,-0.25)$) node[below=2.5mm of smartMeter,fill=white, draw, rectangle]{\textit{First Phase}} ;

    %======================== REPORTING PHASE ===============================
    \coordinate[below=12mm of findSigma](SML6);
    \draw [myarrow] (SML6)--(SML6-|UPL4) coordinate (UPL6) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] (text6) {xxxxxxx};

    \node[hiddenentity] at (SML6-|bankL2) (BL6) {};

%    \node[hiddenentity,below=of BL6] (BL7){};
%    \node[hiddenentity,right=of SML6](UPL6){};

    \node[operation, below=of UPL6] (recordPayment) {xxxxxxx};

    \node[fit=(BL6) (recordPayment) (text6), draw, thick, label={[font=\itshape, fill=white, draw, anchor=center]90:Second Phase}] {};

%    \draw[thick] ($(BL7.north west)+(-0.1,0.25)$) rectangle ($(recordPayment.south east)+(0.1,-0.1)$) node[below=2.5mm of BL6,fill=white, draw, rectangle, rounded corners=0mm]{\textit{Second Phase}} ;
    %==================== REWARDING PHASE ========================
    \coordinate[below=12mm of recordPayment](UPL8);
    \draw [myarrow] (UPL8-|SML6)--(UPL8)  node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] (text8) {xxxxxxx};

%    \node[hiddenentity,left=of UPL8](SML8){};
%    \node[hiddenentity,left=of SML8](BL8){};
%    \draw [myarrow] (SML8.center)--(UPL8.center) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {xxxxxxx};

     \coordinate[below=of UPL8] (UPL9);
    \draw [myarrow] (UPL9)--(UPL9-|bankL2) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {xxxxxxx};

    \node[hiddenentity] at (bankL2|-UPL8) (BL8) {};
    \node[hiddenentity] at (UPL9) (UPL9aux) {};
%    \node[hiddenentity,left=of SML9](BL9){};
%    \draw [myarrow] (UPL9.center)--(BL9.center) node[textAboveArrow,above,midway] {xxxxxxx};

    \node[fit=(BL8) (UPL9aux) (text8), draw, thick, label={[font=\itshape, fill=white, draw, anchor=center]90:Third Phase}] {};

%    \draw[thick] ($(BL8.north west)+(-0.15,0.5)$) rectangle ($(UPL9.south east)+(0.15,-0.1)$) node[below=16mm of BL7,fill=white, draw, rectangle]{\textit{Third Phase}} ;       
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]